# How to Send file and data via raw JSON from Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Currently, I am developing a microservice that receives an image, height, and width to resize that image in this resolution. I have done all my backend side,
now I am struggling on the front side. What I am trying to do is, send an image, height, and width in the same post request from the postman. After searching, I haven't
found a way to do it. I can send it through the request param, but I don't think is the correct way, maybe I am wrong. But, thinking that I have to pass whole my
object through the request param it sounds ugly.

What I am trying to do is, in postman Body JSON/raw pass values of the three attributes which are multipart file that take the image, height, and width
for the resolution. I can successfully pass the width and height, but I don't know how to pass image from the body raw.

Please, can anyone give any idea?

This is my model.

```
public class TaskDTO {
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private MultipartFile multipartfile;
```

Endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/task")
    public void createTask(@RequestBody TaskDTO taskDTO){
        //taskService.createTask(file, width, height);
        //System.out.println(file);
        System.out.println(taskDTO.toString());

        //System.out.println(taskDTO.toString());


    }
```

Postman Test

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using `@ModelAttribute`:

- DTO
  [image]
- Controller[image]
- Postman UI[image]

Comment: Also this topic could be useful for you: https://localcoder.org/how-to-send-the-multipart-file-and-json-data-to-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

You can send file only using `form-data` not `raw`. In this point you will need to search for `@RequestParam MultipartFile file`.

Another point is to send file as array of bytes. But, you will need to convert your file into bytes before.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've tried using the annotation ```@RequestParam```, which only allows sending the file, well also other data. But, what I am trying is, to send the file using ```@RequestParam``` and the JSON data with ```@RequestBody```.

Comment: In this point you should use `@ModelAttribute` and you will be able to send every DTO data as form parameter.

Comment: Could you attach any examples, please?? I've searched a lot, but I don't found anyone who can give me a correct explanation.

Comment: Attached example as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a multipart message.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616667/20654

In postman you select

`POST`

Then form-data and in the key you can select the file

[image: Example]

See this for a more detailed answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022213/20654